# vagrant homestead can't access host(laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

When I goto my host ao.dev:8000 or ao.dev, ***"this site can't be reached,ao.dev refused to connect"*** is displayed.

My yaml file:

[image]

also i've my view file:

i've checked:

[image]

I've run vagrant up command by going to Homestead directory .

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801375/vagrant-up-not-forwarding-all-portshomesteadlaravel-5-2windows-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I was using WAMP before installing homestead.
So I uninstalled both i.e. wamp and homestead setup including vagrant and virtual box.
Then I installed homestead setup again and it worked.
I dont know the logic behind but maybe wamp and homestead were conflicting.
It worked so I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What I needed to do to get my local Laravel up and running:

- use 127.0.0.1 rather than 192.168.10.10 in my hosts file
- make sure the `.env` file had the correct hostname listed as the `APP_URL`
- make sure to use the `:8000` port to access the site

Additionally:

- if you're adding multiple sites, make sure to run `vagrant provision` after adding each site to your `Homestead.yaml`
- not sure if it makes a difference, but you might want to put a space after the colon for the `map` command, i.e. `map: ao.dev`
- I did not need to add `hostname` or `name` elements to `Homestead.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example `Homestead.yaml` file from one of my own projects:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
hostname: vm
name: vm
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "."
      to: "/home/vagrant/example"

sites:
    - map: example.dev
      to: "/home/vagrant/example/public"

databases:
    - example

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

**Notice how my paths are double-quoted** (`to: "/home/vagrant/example"`)? In your code above, these paths are not double-quoted as they should be.

I also recommend after you fix your configuration that you completely destroy and re-create your VM by running:

`vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up`

In your Laravel project root directory.

Comment: @sorry,no effect :(

Comment: Maybe its because you haven't given your VM a `hostname` or `name`. Please add those to the top of your `Homestead.yaml` and try `vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up` again.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that I can see what your `Homestead.yaml` file looks like now?

Comment: What happens when you run `vagrant destroy`?

Comment: this happens: ==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...

Comment: Good! Now run `vagrant up` and see if the site comes online

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120251/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-jamesking56).

Answer (score 0):

Your Vagrant VM machine is up but you can't reach to the machine.

Can you paste your hosts file on your host machine?

Can you paste the output of a "nmap 192.168.10.10" from your host machine?

Can you paste "ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -la" on your Vagrant VM machine?

Comment: are you talking about virtualbox?...yes it says failed to open session for virtual machine.....

Comment: Your Vagrant VM is up. The http://i.stack.imgur.com/Unn5W.png is the Vagrant VM shell. Can you paste this 3 elements, so I can take a look and see what is happening?

Comment: ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -la gives: total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 27 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 27 16:55 ..

Comment: I've this in hosts file: 127.0.0.1 localhost 192.168.10.10 homestead.app 192.168.10.10 ao.dev

Comment: nmap 192.168.10.10 gives: Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-03 08:46 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.10
Host is up (1.0s latency).
Not shown: 987 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
110/tcp  open  pop3
119/tcp  open  nntp
135/tcp  open  msrpc
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
143/tcp  open  imap
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds
465/tcp  open  smtps
563/tcp  open  snews
587/tcp  open  submission
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
5357/tcp open  wsdapi

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 27.84 seconds

Comment: @YaShChaudhary the nmap doesn't show the HTTP port open (80, 443, 8080), so you have some problem with your HTTP server or some firewall/antivirus is blocking the connection.

Comment: Try to provision the Vagrant VM "vagrant reload --provision". Take a look at this post http://www.jesusamieiro.com/how-to-add-a-new-project-in-laravel-homestead/

Comment: this is empty:vagrant@homestead:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ls

Comment: @YaShChaudhary if you have this directory empty this means that you have a problem provisioning the Vagrant VM, because you haven't any site enabled in the nginx.

Comment: so how to enable site?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I installed and run [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and it was enough to solve it.